# What are the security risks of using /bin/sh?

Tags: ssh, security, shell

A friend of mine told me that you should never allow your users to ssh via `/bin/sh` because it has many security issues and people can perform attacks using it. Is it really true? If yes, what are the security risks of it? What attacks can my users perform using /bin/sh if they are not sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When security issues are reported, they get fixed. This is the case for `/bin/sh` as it is for `/bin/[b]ash` or any other UNIX or Linux program that is maintained.

On Debian, by default, `/bin/sh` is linked symbolically to `/bin/dash`, you can change that with `galternatives`.

It is impossible to reply precisely without knowing specifically what your friend meant. Next time you see him, ask your friend for a CVE number, if he cannot give you one, he made it up.

The easiest way to see what `/bin/sh` is linked to is: `ls -l /bin/sh`, again, what it is linked to does not matter, I am not aware of a current security issue in a shell, and without CVE, there is none.

Actually, there is this one: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-16522

However, it is NOT a vulnerability in `/bin/sh`, whatever that is linked to, it is a problem with routers from the company MitraStar, which execute specific commands as `root` and unfortunately allow authenticated users (users who have a username/password on the router) to enter a command such as `/bin/sh`, the command is executed as `root` which allows anybody with a valid username/password for the router full control of the router.

EDIT - From the comments:

The following is a shell script in `/tmp` that just outputs `$0`, I have created a symbolic link in my home directory named `hhh` that points to `/tmp/test.sh`

```
$ echo '#!/bin/sh

echo $0' > /tmp/test.sh
$ chmod +x /tmp/test.sh
$ ln -s /tmp/test.sh hhh
$ ls -l hhh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jdoe Users 12 Dec 18 07:21 hhh -> /tmp/test.sh
$ ./hhh
./hhh
$ $(pwd)/hhh
/home/jdoe/hhh
```

Comment: I don't understand! from what you explained I get `/bin/sh -> dash` but when I ssh via /bin/sh and then do `echo $0` I get `/bin/sh` can you please explain to me what is happening?

Comment: Yes, I corrected my reply, it should be `/bin/dash` iso `/bin/ash`, thanks. Can you please explain to me what is happening? This is a completely different question that requires a long answer. Suffice to say, the symbolic link points to `/bin/dash`, the symbolic link (`/bin/sh`) is executed, so that is what `echo $0` returns, what else would you expect it to return ?

Comment: What I don't understand is if it's symbolically linked to dash, then why the name of the process is still /bin/sh from when I do `echo $0`.

Comment: @aran that's just how symlinks work, take a look at shell args manual. it has nothing to do with ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is wrong. On many (most) systems /bin/sh is really a link to another shell e.g. on CentOS it's /bin/bash and on Ubuntu it's /bin/dash. You should ask your friend to elaborate on the security issues they think are exposed via /bin/sh.

Comment: How can I verify that is the case in my system? ( I mean whether it's linked to another bash or not?)

Comment: Anyway my system is Debian.

Comment: @aran run `ls -l /bin/sh`